# How to show finished project?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am a complete, absolute beginner so please excuse my ignorance!

I have created my first 'coding project' using Visual Studio Code IDE in Python, here is a link to it below:

https://github.com/monicaneill/Projects/blob/master/guessinggame.py

Basically my question is how do I show this to others in a way that they can interact with it and not just look at a bunch of text? I'm really proud of my achievement and want other people to be able to play the game who might not have the likes of Visual Studio etc to run the code, is there any way I can do this so someone on say Facebook could open up a file and then run the game?

Thank you so much and apologies in advance if this is not the right place to ask this sort of question!

Comment: they can install python and run your script or you can convert it to an executable for a particular platform. Search for `python to exe`. The beauty of python is that any platform that you can install python on can run the script

Answer (score 1):

A python file needs the python runtime to be run. With the python runtime on your system, you can simply do, in your terminal-

```
> python guessinggame.py
```

(assuming `guessinggame.py` is on the same directory)

However, I assume you want people to be able to run the code without having the python runtime installed.

In that case, you need to compile your python code to an executable native binary. There are tools to aid in this process - perhaps the most straightforward tool is `pyinstaller`

Firstly, you need to install `pyinstaller` in your own system-

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Now, in your terminal, you simply have to do-

```
pyinstaller guessinggame.py
```

(Make sure you're on the same folder where `guessinggame.py` is)

This will create a folder on the same directory that contains all the files needed to launch your script as well as an `.exe` (if you're on windows) - your friends will only need this folder and all they have to do is run the `.exe`

You can find more information about `pyinstaller` and how to make executables with it [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-folder)

Comment: Another option is [Briefcase](https://briefcase.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score -2):

Search by flask -> [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/)

I think this is more or less what you are looking for.

Comment: what does flask have to do with this?

Comment: I consider it a practical tool in the case of those who are starting to expose their application in some way, which seemed to be the case, I may be wrong eventually.

Comment: flask is a web framework, not a way to build executables